# Error to use terminal commands on PHP with Mac OS MAMP

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I'm using MAMP 6.5 - Build 33813 (Macbook Air M1 2020) to make some Apache hosts.

All everything is ok, except one thing. I can't use terminal commands on my PHP code (exec, copy, and others).

I uninstalled my Brew PHP and using only MAMP PHP 7.2 and 8.0 (CGI).

I receive no errors or logs, just doesn't work. This is my terminal's response when I run `php -v`:

```sh
PHP 7.2.34 (cli) (built: Aug  5 2021 15:20:02) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

[Image - PHP MAMP Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQFtK.png)

Comment: Do you mean calling those commands from web scripts isn't working? Or do you mean running scripts at the command line isn't working?

Comment: Running the PHP function didn't work, the same command via terminal returned normally. I formatted the notebook, I think it's a conflict between PHP from MAMP, Brew or Docker.